# Grabbing text inside a <p> tag in between <b> tags plus a regex issue

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

Ok, so I have gotten really close and need help crossing the finish line. I have two pieces of text that I want to grab using Scrapy. Here is the format:

```
<html>
  <div id="product-description">
    <p>
      Blah blah blah text text text reads: 874620. more text text.
      <br>
      <br>
      <b>Brand:</b>
      " Nintendo"
      <br>
      <b>Condition:</b>
      " Good"
    </p>
  </div>
</html>
```

So far I am only able to grab the bolded headings (Brand:, Condition:), not the text I actually want (Nintendo, Good). Similarly with regex, I am only grabbing "reads:" instead of the string immediately after which is what I want (874620). Here is where I am:

```
response.xpath('//div[@id="product-description"]//p/b').extract_first()

response.xpath('//div[@id="product-description"]//p').re(r'reads.*')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can extract the whole text of the `<p>` tag and then run regex to extract the relevant information from it

example code:

```
import re
from scrapy.selector import Selector

html = '''<html>
  <div id="product-description">
    <p>
      Blah blah blah text text text reads: 874620. more text text.
      <br>
      <br>
      <b>Brand:</b>
      " Nintendo"
      <br>
      <b>Condition:</b>
      " Good"
    </p>
  </div>
</html>'''

extracted_text = Selector(text=html).xpath('//div[@id="product-description"]//p//text()').extract()
text = u''.join(extracted_text)

regex = r'reads:\s*(?P<reads>\d+).*Brand:\s*" (?P<brand>\w+)".*Condition:\s*" (?P<condition>\w+)"'
results = re.search(regex, text, flags=re.DOTALL).groupdict()

results['reads'] = int(results['reads'])
print(results)
```

this code outputs:

```
{'reads': 874620, 'brand': u'Nintendo', 'condition': u'Good'}
```

### Update:

lets see what this code does:

**xpath**

first, the `extracted_text` takes all the text inside the `<p>` tag using the xpath `//div[@id="product-description"]//p//text()`
this xpath means:

- give me all the divs that has an id attribute matching the
  "product-description"
- give me all the p tags inside the divs above
- get the text out of these p tags

**note**: the `//` instead of `/` means include on the search for tags also the child of childrens and their childrens and so on.

running this xpath returns list of strings for each text of the tags inside the `<p>` tag we found.

after the xpath, we concatenate this list into large string using the `u''.join(extracted_text)`.

after getting the full text we want we can run regex to extract the relevant data from it.

**regex**

lets try to break down the regex and see what it means:

`reads:\s*(?P<reads>\d+).*Brand:\s*" (?P<brand>\w+)".*Condition:\s*" (?P<condition>\w+)"`

`reads:\s*(?P<reads>\d+)` - find me a string starting with `reads:`. followed by zero or more white spaces `\s*` and create a match group called *reads* containing `\d+` meaning one or more digits.

`.*Brand:\s*" (?P<brand>\w+)"` - the above is followed by zero or more characters (any characters), the string `Brand:` and again `\s*` zero or more white spaces followed by double quote and single space `"`. after this create another group called *brand* which contains `\w+` meaning one or more alphanumeric letters.

`.*Condition:\s*" (?P<condition>\w+)"` - this is the same as the second part above, create a matching group for *condition*

the regex is executed with the flag [DOTALL](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) which means the `.` char matches all characters (including new line) because our match is across multi lines.

after running the above regex we extract the 3 matching groups and convert from string to int the reads match.

**I uploaded this example to [here](https://regex101.com/r/anijIM/1) which contains detail info and its interactive so you can try it yourself.**

Comment: Could you break down what is going on here a little bit more? Particularly the results and regex variables. I am trying to learn regex and want to understand the mechanics a little better. Thx!

Comment: Unbelievable! Thank you for such an amazing answer!!

Answer (score 1):

For the `Nintendo, Good` value you can use `following-sibling` feature:

```
In [1]: sel.xpath('//div[@id="product-description"]//b/following-sibling::text()[1]').extract()
Out[1]: [u'\n      " Nintendo"\n      ', u'\n      " Good"\n    ']
```

You can add regex to avoid the ugly spaces:

```
In [2]: sel.xpath('//div[@id="product-description"]//b/following-sibling::text()[1]').re('"(.+)"')
Out[2]: [u' Nintendo', u' Good']
```

Regarding your second issue with regex, try this one:

```
In [3]: sel.xpath('//div[@id="product-description"]//p').re('reads: (\d+)')
Out[3]: [u'874620']
```

Comment: The first two work well. For the third, I am getting an empty list as the result. If I delete `(\d+)` I correctly get `[u'reads: ']` but with `(\d+)` I get `[ ]`. Any ideas?